# Unity3D: Sudden lighting change in a scene

Tags: unity, lighting

> Sorry if this is a duplicate question, but I have no idea what this would be considered.

Hello, I have recently been creating an FPS game, but while researching some things on the internet, the lighting changes within only one scene. I actually want to keep this change, but I am not sure what changed to make it look like this.

It unusually changed from this: [image: Image of the scene without lighting changes]

To this: [image: Image of the scene with lighting changes]

I want to keep the new one, but have this same lighting effect on a different scene, however, I am not sure what can cause this change. I have searched high and low for anything that could've changed, but I couldn't find anything. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I fixed this is to go to the Lighting menu at `Window > Lighting` and configure the Lightmaps to Auto.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem of random lighting change. My dark scene suddenly was bright. I went to Window/Lighting Settings/Object maps and turned off Auto Generate and that fixed it for me.